# Characters left in textbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

So I have looked all over the place and I have found a lot of answers which all say pretty much the same thing. Some have been in C# and some have been in ASP.NET but none of them are working.

Here is my problem. I have a textbox and I also have a label. My textbox allows the user to enter 500 characters into the textbox and I want the label to say how many characters the user has left. I figured this would be easy to do, but nothing is working! So here is what I got so far:

The label I want to show the characters is called lblAboutCount and the textbox is txtAbout.

```
private void txtAbout_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var max = txtAbout.MaxLength;
  var length = txtAbout.Text.Length;
  var total = max - length;

  lblAboutCount.Text = total.ToString(); 
}
```

I have put the code in the TextChanged, KeyPress and KeyUp events and none of them worked. I also have on the start of the form:

`lblAboutCount.Text = txtAbout.MaxLength.ToString()`

I do not know what I am doing wrong!!

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: `TextChanged` should be a fine place to update the current length remaining. Please be more specific than "nothing is working!". What exactly does happen? How, specifically, is that different from what you want to happen? Please show [a minimal, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I agree with Peter, we need more info. Does it throw an error, does it not give the right answer, does the label not change etc...

Comment: Oh sorry I thought I said what was happening. Because I put in the frmload function to make the label show the max number of characters the textbox can take, it shows the correct number of characters it can take. When I type in the textbox, the label doesn't change at all. It stays at 500. I showed you all of the code above, and the code

`lblAboutCount.Text = txtAbout.MaxLength.ToString()`

is in the public frmMain(). Hopefully this helps a little more

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas with this? I really don't get why it wouldn't be working

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that this works as expected here.

You do have this line in your partial class (Designer>View code)

```
this.txtAbout.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtAbout_TextChanged);
```

don't you?

Comment: No, I just went to the event and wrote the code. Where would that go?

Answer (score 0):

So after thinking about this for hours and not getting the correct answer I thought about the actual text box that I was using. I am using a theme on my form and the theme comes with all of the elements that I need like a textbox, check box, label, etc.

So I deleted the theme text box and put a normal text box and did the exact code I showed you and there was not one problem with it. I never even gave it a thought to tell you guys about the textbox because in the code the text box inherits text box so I figured it wad just a normal text box and ut wouldn't affect that. Sorry for the problems everyone!

this should help other people who are using themes and are having problems with things like that. I also could not change the background color of the text box when a user was typing until I used a normal text box.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but for future seekers:

You might want to consider using TextChanging event instead of TextChanged.  In doing so, you can not only update your label to show how many characters are left, but you can also set e.Cancel=true to disallow entering of any more text beyond your desired limit.  Like this...

```
        if (txtTitle.Text.Length > 80)
            e.Cancel = true;
        else
            lblTitleCharsLeft.Text = $"({80 - txtTitle.Text.Length} chars left)";
```